# changing the db used with cucumber to the _test db instead of _development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

For whatever reason, my cucumber is using my _development db instead of my _test db.

How do I change that?

This is what my database.yml says

```
test: &test
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: myapp_test
```

but i get the error database configuration does not specify adapter

This is also at the bottom.... I can only assume that this is SUPPOSSED to set it to use the test db

```
cucumber: &CUCUMBER
  <<: *test
culerity:
  <<: *CUCUMBER
```

but, alas, the test db is never touched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have something like:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
```

in your features/support/env.rb file?

Comment: I didn't have that. But I added it, restarted the server, and it is still using the dev db.. /=

Comment: Also, when using Capybara, the server needs to be running with the test env.